# Cocos2d-js: projects need to be that huge?

Tags: android, cocos2d-js

I'm trying out `cocos2d-js` (version 3.0) and even the simplest 'Hello World' project is over 1 gigabyte in size when it is created.

Is this normal? (I have a habit of creating dozens of demo-projects when trying out a new platform, but it looks like I need to get myself a bigger SSD, just for this!)

Also, the size of the apk, when compiled for Android, is about 9 MB. Any ways to reduce this size?

Answer (score 1):

Sadly, yes. I've [mentioned this](http://discuss.cocos2d-x.org/t/excessive-disk-space-consuption/17138) in the community a [couple of times](http://discuss.cocos2d-x.org/t/resolved-compiling-is-way-too-slow/12077) to no avail. I believe this files should be referenced/cached in a common location for all projects, but the dev team seems to have other priorities at present.

If you wish to keep your projects you'll be better off heading to their `frameworks` directory and deleting all folders except `cocos2d-html5` (this one should be 5MB only) in there. -
An alternative would be to also delete the `cocos2d-html5` folder, place it in a common dir (or use the copy in your install folder) and reference the path properly in your projetc's config file. Keep in mind this option may break code suggesstion/autocomplete in some editors, and throw errors in your webserver when you try to run the project.-

This way, you'll be able to run any of those projects in the browser, and then only add the files neccessary for native compilation in projects you wish to test in the emulator or your device (or compile for publishing). This will sadly take a lot of time to copy and re-generate the files, of course.

---

As for reducing the size of the `.apk`s... I don't know a way. I know efforts are being made to optimize the binder, and there may be a way to explicitly avoid packaging unused stuff, but I don't know about it.

Answer (score 1):

You can reduce the app size in Cocos2d-js v3.2 released in January. It allows you to exclude the unused modules. Refer to the [upgrade guide](http://www.cocos2d-x.org/docs/manual/framework/html5/release-notes/v3.2rc0/upgrade-guide/en)  for more details on how to do this. The minimum apk size for Android is 4.4mb .